# How to get camera screen in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

In my android app, I am trying to do some image recognition, and I want to open the camera and see the camera generated images before even taking a pic, like the camera browse mode.

Basically as you browse I want to continuously grab the current screen and then read it and generate some object to update some text on the screen. Something like this

```
@Override
// this gets called every 5 seconds while in camera browse mode. bitmap is the image of the camera currently
public void getScreen(Bitmap bitmap) {
    MyData data = myalgorithm(bitmap);
    displayCountOnScreen(data);
}
```

I saw this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.cartooncamera&hl=en

and in camera browse mode, they change the screen and put some other GUI stuff on the screen. I want to do that too.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the [Camera Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is put some GUI elements on the screen, then there is no need to fetch all the preview frames as Bitmaps (though you could do that as well, if you want):

Create a layout with a SurfaceView for where you want the video data to appear, and then put other views on top.

In onCreate, you can get it like this:

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);  // For when you need to know when it changes.
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

When you create a camera, you need to pass it a Surface to display the preview on, see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder):

```
    Camera camera  = ...        
    ...
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    camera.startPreview();
```

If you want to do image recognition, what you want are the raw image bytes to work with. In this case, register a PreviewCallback, see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)